# How can I redirect part of traffic

Tags: nginx

I'd want to achieve something like that

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   example.com *.example.com;
    location / {

        if (requestNumber % 2 == 0)
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        else
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:7000;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

So, basically every 2nd request is going to be routed to different port

Or if possible every 2nd IP is going to be routed to different port

Is it possible to achieve something like that?

Comment: Will the [upstream module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html) work for you?

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks, it works fine!